# Angular app.component.html is not rendering new component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am facing some issues trying to rendering my new component in the browser. I have created a new project using the **Angular CLI**. Also I created a component called `list-employees`.

When I execute `ng serve -o`, the project is compiled succesfully but the browser does not show anything (blank page both IE and Google Chrome). Even the web console in Chrome does not show any error message, instead prints *Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.*

If I change content in the **app.component.html**:

```
 <app-list-employees></app-list-employees>
```

and I put static HTML instead:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

the browser shows the content as expected. This seems weird to me because I am not getting any error. Please can you help me to understand why is this happening?

Here the content of **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "crud",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.15",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.12",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

And here the output from app.componen.html when I call the list-employees component:

```
<body>
    <app-root _nghost-xoo-c0="" ng-version="8.2.12">
    <app-list-employees _ngcontent-xoo-c0="" _nghost-xoo-c1="">
    <!--bindings={}-->
    </app-list-employees>
    </app-root>
    <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>  
 </body>
```

**UPDATED**

Here the respective code:

**list-employees.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-employees',
  templateUrl: './list-employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-employees.component.css']
})
export class ListEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  employee: Employee[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Mark',
      gender: 'Male',
      contactPreference: 'Email',
      email: 'mark@pragimtech.com',
      dateOfBirth: new Date('10/25/1988'),
      department: 'IT',
      isActive: true,
      photoPath: 'assets/images/mark.png'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Mary',
      gender: 'Female',
      contactPreference: 'Phone',
      phoneNumber: '2345978640',
      dateOfBirth: new Date('11/20/1979'),
      department: 'HR',
      isActive: true,
      photoPath: 'assets/images/mary.png'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'John',
      gender: 'Male',
      contactPreference: 'Phone',
      phoneNumber: '5432978640',
      dateOfBirth: new Date('3/25/1976'),
      department: 'IT',
      isActive: false,
      photoPath: 'assets/images/john.png'
    },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**list-employees.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" *ngFor="let employee of employees">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{employee.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="row vertical-align">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img class="imageSize" [src]="employee.photoPath"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            Gender:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            {{employee.gender}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            Birth of date:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            {{employee.dateOfBirth | date}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          Contact Preference:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          {{employee.contactPreference}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          Phone:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          {{employee.phoneNumber}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          Email:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          {{employee.email}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            Department:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            {{employee.department}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            Is active:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            {{employee.isActive}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-list-employees></app-list-employees>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListEmployeesComponent } from './employees/list-employees.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListEmployeesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You should probably include the code of the appModule, of the custom component, etc. Better yet, you could upload the code to StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular Without that, it's really hard to guess what's going on. Things you should check: 1 have you the ListEmployees component declared in the App Module? 2 is the selector of the ListEmployeesComponent actually app-list-employees? 3 what is the html template of ListEmployeesComponent? I would guess that the child component is not properly resolved.

Comment: If you correctly declared the Component in your module - then I would suggest double checking the spelling of `app-list-employees` in your component.

Comment: @A.Chiesa Thank you for your suggestion.I have added the respective code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in `ListEmployeesComponent` you are cycling the `employees` property, which doesn't exist.

Instead, there is a wrongly named employee (without s) property, containing the array.

I would suggest installing the Angular Language Service plugin (if it's available in your text editor, I use VS Code), that would catch that kind of error underlining the offending line in red.

Comment: You are right, now it is working. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome! Try the list in this article to better setup your environment and catch this kind of bugs: https://johnpapa.net/rec-ng-extensions/